# In typescript how to restrict the list of properties passed to a function as a parameter?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have this:

```
export interface RegionNode {
    nodeSelected: boolean;
    nodeEditable: boolean;
    zone: Partial<Zone>;
    parent: RegionNode | null;
    children: RegionNode[];
}
```

And I would like a generic function doing this:

```
function setNodeAndChildrenProperty(node: RegionNode, property: keyof RegionNode, state: boolean): void {
    // @ts-ignore
    node[property] = state;
    for (const child of node.children) {
        setNodeAndChildrenProperty(child, property, state);
    };
}
```

But as you can see I had to use @ts-ignore, as I don't know how to restrict the list of allowed properties to "nodeSelected" and "nodeEditable" among other issues.

What is the elegant way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by having a mapped type that will return a type for just the properties assignable to a given type (in your case, `boolean`):

```typescript
type PropertiesOfType<ObjType, PropType> = {
    [Key in keyof ObjType as ObjType[Key] extends PropType ? Key : never]: ObjType[Key];
};
```

The `as` clause in the `[Key in ____]` omits keys (by using `never`) for properties that aren't assignable to the target property type. So for instance, `PropertiesOfType<RegionNode, boolean>` gives us this type:

```typescript
{
    nodeSelected: boolean;
    nodeEditable: boolean;
}
```

Then you can use that in your function, so TypeScript knows that the type of `node[property]` is compatible with the type of `state`:

```typescript
function setNodeAndChildrenProperty(
    node: RegionNode,
    property: keyof PropertiesOfType<RegionNode, boolean>, // <====
    state: boolean
): void {
    node[property] = state;
    node.children.forEach((child) => {
        setNodeAndChildrenProperty(child, property, state);
    });
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGUBcEMDsBMC0BLWAoVkCmAnAZtAMZagBaA9rCQN5qj2jQBcoAzpDqgOYDcdDAIxbtOsXmgC+aNFgAeAB3I5IoTLgLFQAJSxdklAHLl4NfvVjGs4LABsshbPBYDy5O3D4NQFkwFF4yDACds6u7rCeDABelFgsAArQysjQNgA8FFQAfJH08klYsJAsOnqGlqAAPt4ArjY2uaCEABbINvA4hSW6+rBGJgDaALp8UmiQAJ7yJPE45NPJWKwA8ngAKlNYacsCAFYb0wA0oLPzB1hZoAC8oLReAwDSWBOqsKAA1s-keKA7+5uMVi-PbnR7PIagOTYBBA07yc6gAD8oCeLxYVAAbrghiw-qDUSNJHw0HgarAHL02FhIP0sABBBAAYVa7U6sDhuEmAAozN5LN0yn1LIdefI5gtJixPhNvidxZzkEtVuc0qVerTji43Fg4FkRV52NBsKFtXA0ABKFgY8jIeC3Xk+LADMXzTkTCE3Q3YRqOgB0LTaHUKvrwSl8RGaXK5Afa5uulzuXgYrGptIZ8GZgbZHOUE2jLPgxxdEomxy9WHNjQklckQA)